# IIS Virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

I try to route my PDF files trough my `global.asax` to check accessrights.

I add to my web.config for this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

And

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="*.pdf" type="Pipeline.TimeHandler, Pipeline" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

This works fine unless my files are on a IIS virtual directory.

Requested informations:

**What version of IIS do you use?**
Microsoft-IIS/7.5

**Do you use Integrated or Classic mode?**
It run in Integrated mode.

**Does the request get transfered to your handler at all?**
I don't really have a handler, I just wan't to use the Integreated handler.

**Does it run Application_BeginRequest?**
No It don't even hit `Application_BeginRequest`

**Do you have any non-standard ISAPI modules installed in IIS?**
No, I think not.

I edit my web.config to:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
     <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
     <add name="*_AppService.axd_*" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
     <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="PdfHandler" verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="Pipeline.TimeHandler, Pipeline" />
    </handlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

And I remove the `httpHandlers` and with this i got an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Pipeline' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I think the problem is `` `type="Pipeline.TimeHandler, Pipeline" `` don't work. But what should I configure there to use the standart IIS pipline to that `Application_AuthenticateRequest` get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically [Luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) answer is right.

In my specific case, it turns out that the virtual directory was a virtual application with its own pipeline and everything. So I just delete that, and add it as virtual directory this works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing Integrated mode and Classic mode configuration. It seems that your IIS is configured in Integrated mode (which has settings in system.webServer), while you're registering your HTTP handler in Classic mode (system.web).

Try adding this to your system.webServer configuration section:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="Pipeline.TimeHandler, Pipeline" />
</handlers>
```

If this isn't your problem, please provide more information:

- What version of IIS do you use?
- Do you use Integrated or Classic mode?
- Does the request get transfered to your handler at all? Does it run Application_BeginRequest?
- Do you have any non-standard ISAPI modules installed in IIS?

And any other useful information you can get.

Note that in Classic mode, you also have to set the ASP.NET ISAPI module to handle all requests (by default, it only handles requests to *.aspx, *.asmx etc.), or at least add *.pdf.

EDIT: Oh, so you don't actually have your own handler for PDFs? In that case, you only need to make sure the authentication runs for static files (the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests should be enough), and you have to make sure the user actually needs some permissions to read your files. You have to deny access to files in your directory by configuration. For example, you can add this to the web.config in the directory you've got your files in:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This basically says: Deny access to all anonymous (ie. not logged in) users.

Comment: `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests should be enough` should but in combination with impersonating and the other things Application_BeginRequest & Application_AuthenticateRequest don't get executed

Comment: @Sirl33tname And have you tried adding the authorization configuration I mentioned? Otherwise it simply passes without invoking any authorization, since the default is "allow everyone".

Comment: Yes, I have this in my web.config since the beginnig

Comment: Now I have write my own Handler but if I load them with `type="Handler.PdfHandler, ProjektName"` I got an error: `Could not load file or assembly 'ProjektName' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: @Sirl33tname If you're writing a web site (not a web project), assembly names can get screwy. Try just using the short name, without assembly name (ie. just "Handler.PdfHandler").

Comment: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Handler.PdfHandler'. I try this :/

Comment: Where did you put your handler? And is it (sorry for even asking) a public class? Are you sure the namespace and name is correct? Are you using a web site or a web project?

Comment: I put my handler first in App_Code and after in my Project root. I double check my class is public and the namespace. Whats the differenc between web site and web project?

Comment: Basically, a web project has a single DLL as an output (along with the usual aspx files and such, but not .cs files). A web site is compiled per-directory instead, so in deployment, it produces many DLLs, which are then merged together. If you can set an assembly name in project properties -> Application, it's probably a web project. Well, if this didn't work, try making a new DLL with just your PdfHandler and add that as a reference to the web project/site, and add it with an Assembly Qualified Name in handlers.